# UPDATE records with conditions in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a following query

```
SELECT count(Distinct user_bookmarks.user_id) AS bookmark_counter, bookmark_id 
FROM user_bookmarks 
LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON user_bookmarks.bookmark_id = bookmarks.id 
group by user_bookmarks.bookmark_id
```

which is working fine

Now I want to update records from bookmarks table

```
UPDATE bookmark 
set bookmarks_counter = bookmark_counter from from above query 
where id = bookmark_id which is again from above query
```

from above query

Any idea?

Can we do this?

Thanks

Comment: you have not mentioned table name in above update query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write in a query in your update like so

```
UPDATE bookmark bk,
(   SELECT count(Distinct user_bookmarks.user_id) AS bookmark_counter, bookmark_id 
    FROM user_bookmarks 
    LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON user_bookmarks.bookmark_id = bookmarks.id 
    GROUP BY user_bookmarks.bookmark_id
) t
SET bk.bookmarks_counter = t.bookmark_counter
WHERE bk.id = t.bookmark_id
```

Comment: @HituBansal no problem! :) when you can if you can accept the answer i would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: i will take some time. Doesn't allowing me to do so

Comment: @HituBansal i know :) just encouraging +1 to you as well!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
UPDATE dbo.bookmarks SET bookmarks_counter = result 
WHERE user_bookmarks.user_id 
IN (SELECT count(Distinct user_bookmarks.user_id)
    AS bookmark_counter, bookmark_id  FROM user_bookmarks 
    LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON user_bookmarks.bookmark_id =  bookmarks.id  
    GROUP BY user_bookmarks.bookmark_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 UPDATE
   bookmark 
SET 
   bookmark.bookmarks_counter = other.bookmark_counter 

FROM
    (SELECT count(Distinct user_bookmarks.user_id) AS bookmark_counter, bookmark_id 
FROM user_bookmarks 
LEFT JOIN bookmarks ON user_bookmarks.bookmark_id = bookmarks.id 
group by user_bookmarks.bookmark_id) other
WHERE 
   bookmark.id = other.bookmark_id
```